# Timer Countdown (Confused)

Tags: php, date

Basically, I am trying to make a timer or countdown in PHP. This will take the time saved in the threads (date of post) and then show how long ago that is in comparison to the current time.

Anybody know how to do this?

Code:

```
<?php foreach($this->updated as $thread){ ?>
    <section>
        <div class="body">
            <?php if($this->threads[$thread]['image']!='') { ?>
                <div>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->threads[$thread]['image']; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->threads[$thread]['image']; ?>">
                </a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php echo $this->threads[$thread]['post']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="small text-right">
            <?php echo count($this->threads[$thread]['posts']); ?> Replies
            &nbsp; | &nbsp;
            <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $this->threads[$thread]['time']); ?> EST
            &nbsp; | &nbsp;
            <a href="/<?php echo $thread; ?>">View</a>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php  } ?>
```

I don't want it to be an exact timer, more like it would say for example "less than a minute ago", "1 minute ago", "2 minutes ago", etc...

I have tried to make 2 different variables and then did $current->diff($date); Then just echo $diff->h for example for the hour. But I was confused by the matter.

Comment: You appear to have made no attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: Updated my post, I was in the middle of typing when I accidentally posted it.

Comment: Do a search here for "fuzzy time" or "fuzzy date", that should get you a few answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$timestamp = 1421253112;
$date = new DateTime;
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$now = new DateTime;
$interval = $now->diff($date);
echo $interval->format('%i minutes ago');
```

Output:

```
7 minutes ago
```

Comment: Would this be possible without having to set a timezone? Could it just be based off the time on the users computer? And how would I incorporate this with my $this->threads[$thread]['time'] being the posted time.

Comment: @user3807836 Yes, try without timezone. I added it to avoid the errors in my test script. Just use your variable `$this->threads[$thread]['time']` instead of $timestamp.